# Eclipse Neon spell checking discards user suggestions

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking

I am attempting to use Eclipse spell checking on Eclipse Neon 3 running on Ubuntu 17.04. When I encounter a misspelled word I click Ctrl-1 on the word and a list box pops up with a list of suggestions and I select **add to dictionary**. However when I return from the list box the word is still marked as misspelled and has not been inserted into the user dictionary.

I have verified that spell checking is specified in the Eclipse preferences and that the location of the dictionary and its' permissions are OK.

How should I go about trouble shooting this problem?